# Pavers vs concrete walkway

Tags: construction, landscaping

What are the pros and cons of constructing a walkway with pavers instead of concrete? Also if pavers are used for the walkway will they eventually have to be replaced?  Can weather affect the pavers such as cause shifting, etc.   When the house and porch are pressure washed will it affect the pavers and can weeds grow between the pavers.   TIA

Comment: One consideration is the push toward permeable parking surfaces. The US trend of three-stall garages and massive driveways has led to runoff and pollution issues in adjacent waterways. Some municipalities now limit the portion of a lot that's allowed to be paved with non-permeable surfaces. It's better to let rainwater permeate into the soil where it can be sanitized and filtered.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Thanks - interested in opinions.

Answer (score 4):

Pavers:
* Reasonable to do yourself.
* Probably lower cost.  (2" of concrete, instead of 4"
* No cracking issues.
* Look cool (My opinion)
* If you are creative you can make interesting patterns.  Most come in at least pinky-red, charcoal, and natural.  Sometimes you can get white.

Pavers with a lock patter (zig-zag) and spacer nubs to leave a consistent crack are easier to work with.  But the wider crack (3/32 to 1/8) gives more opportunity for weeds to get established.

Pavers downsides:
* Weeds *will* grow in the cracks.  A flame weeder is quick to use when weeds are small.
* Pavers are a nuisance to shovel snow off of.  The edges aren't perfect, and can catch the edge or corner of a shovel.

Concrete:
* Quick.  2-3 days of inconvenience and they are done.  Pavers can be pretty fast to if done by pros, but not as fast as concrete.

Other options:

Breezeblocks.

I ran into these in college.  Make great bookshelf supports.  Reasonable way to get privacy inexpensively.  But the blocks can also be laid horizontally, and the spaces filled with grass, or other ground cover.  This leaves the surface quite permeable to rain.  Recommended if you want part of the lawn available for parking an RV.  The grass will wear where it gets driven on regularly.

Patio pavers.

Pavers writ large.  Usually 24x24 or 24x30.  These have to have a VERY solidly packed base if you are going to drive on them, as they are usually only 1.5" thick.  There was a fad in California some decades ago to put in 2 strips of patio pavers to the garage, and to use pavers for walkways.  They come in various patterns and colours.

Road crush:  This is what your local county puts on the gravel roads.  It's quick, cheap, and if you put edges on it can look neat.  If the crush is limestone or sandstone based you can 'fix' it in place with dilute muriatic acid.  This dissolves the calcium carbonate, which when the solution dried out, cements the rocks together.  You can also white wash the rocks.  It doesn't last very long, but whitewash is cheap.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Individual pavers typically weather just the same as poured concrete, and should last decades. They're typically bedded on sand over gravel, and can settle if there's a lot of water flowing over them. Weeds can grow between them, I've found moss to be the most common issue, mostly in shaded and low traffic areas. Pressure washing the pavers can again displace the sand, but locally lifting sections to re-level them is easy.

If you're looking for decades with low maintenance, concrete would be the choice. Where I live, however, there's a lot of frost heave action with the winter weather, so it's not perfect for every situation.

Comment: Poly sand really helps to lock them in place and reduce weeds, but pressure washing will take it up.